# Spring boot exception after adding validation to model

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

Well, I think I'm the first one having this issue on the google!

I have a working spring boot project but when I added validation to my model and enable it at the Controller, it gives me the following exception:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "org.springframework.validation.BeanPrope[...]e [Value cannot be empty]", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:870) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:355) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:188) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:60) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
```

Pretty weird for me! it sounds somehow

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPrope[...]e [Value cannot be empty]
```

is misplaced as the template name!!!

Here is my maven dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.webitalkie</groupId>
  <artifactId>web-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>instagram-robot</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <!-- <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- and the 'Thymeleaf Layout Dialect'  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Here is the User model:

```
package com.webitalkie.web.model;

import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class User {

    @NotBlank(message="{emptyValue}")
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank(message="{emptyValue}")
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String lastName;
    @NotBlank(message="{emptyValue}")
    @Size(min=11, max=11)
    private String cell;
    @Email(message="{invalidEmail}")
    private String email;
    @NotBlank(message="{emptyValue}")
    @Size(min=6, max=30)
    private String password;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getCell() {
        return cell;
    }
    public void setCell(String cell) {
        this.cell = cell;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

And this is the Controller:

```
package com.webitalkie.web.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CookieValue;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.webitalkie.instagram_robot.model.User;

@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/*/home", "/home"})
@Validated
public class Home {

    @Autowired
    private HttpSession session;

    @GetMapping(path = "/register")
    public String register(Map<String, Object> model) {

        model.put("user", null);

        return "home/register";
    }

    @PostMapping(path="/createaccount")
    public String makeRegister(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, 
            @RequestParam(name="confirm_password", required=false) String confirmPassword,
            BindingResult result) {

        if(result.hasErrors()) {

            return "redirect:/home/register";
        }

        return "redirect:/home/index";
    }
}
```

When I leave the fields blank and submit the form in register template to createaccount action, it throws mentioned exception.
If I remove the @Valid annotation in makeRegister method, It works fine!

This is my entire console output (exceptions trimmed to save characters count):

```
2017-12-11 14:28:08.091  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] com.webitalkie.web.App       : Starting App on mohamad with PID 24864 (/mnt/backup/MarsWorkplace/web-project/target/classes started by mohamad in /mnt/backup/MarsWorkplace/web-project)
2017-12-11 14:28:08.093  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] com.webitalkie.web.App       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-12-11 14:28:08.418  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6948863d: startup date [Mon Dec 11 14:28:08 IRST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-11 14:28:10.444  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-12-11 14:28:10.458  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-12-11 14:28:10.459  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2017-12-11 14:28:10.680  INFO 24864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-12-11 14:28:10.681  INFO 24864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2266 ms
2017-12-11 14:28:10.830  INFO 24864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-12-11 14:28:10.834  INFO 24864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-11 14:28:10.834  INFO 24864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-11 14:28:10.834  INFO 24864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-11 14:28:10.835  INFO 24864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-11 14:28:10.835  INFO 24864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'resourceUrlEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-11 14:28:11.061  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : testdb - Starting...
2017-12-11 14:28:11.273  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : testdb - Start completed.
2017-12-11 14:28:11.320  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-11 14:28:11.336  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-12-11 14:28:11.426  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.11.Final}
2017-12-11 14:28:11.428  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-12-11 14:28:11.483  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-12-11 14:28:11.597  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2017-12-11 14:28:11.902  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-11 14:28:12.323  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6948863d: startup date [Mon Dec 11 14:28:08 IRST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-11 14:28:12.410  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/*/home || /home],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.webitalkie.web.controller.Home.indexWithNoSlash(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
2017-12-11 14:28:12.411  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/*/home/ || /home/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.webitalkie.web.controller.Home.indexWithSlash(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
2017-12-11 14:28:12.412  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/*/home/login || /home/login],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.webitalkie.web.controller.Home.login(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
2017-12-11 14:28:12.412  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/*/home/createaccount || /home/createaccount],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.webitalkie.web.controller.Home.makeRegister(com.webitalkie.web.model.User,java.lang.String,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-12-11 14:28:12.413  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/*/home/index || /home/index],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.webitalkie.web.controller.Home.index(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
2017-12-11 14:28:12.413  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/*/home/register || /home/register],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.webitalkie.web.controller.Home.register(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.String)
2017-12-11 14:28:12.418  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-12-11 14:28:12.419  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-12-11 14:28:12.496  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-11 14:28:12.497  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-11 14:28:12.542  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-11 14:28:13.115  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2017-12-11 14:28:13.224  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-12-11 14:28:13.226  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-12-11 14:28:13.232  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2017-12-11 14:28:13.285  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-12-11 14:28:13.290  INFO 24864 --- [  restartedMain] com.webitalkie.web.App       : Started App in 5.52 seconds (JVM running for 6.051)
2017-12-11 14:28:27.279  INFO 24864 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-12-11 14:28:27.279  INFO 24864 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-12-11 14:28:27.294  INFO 24864 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 14 ms
2017-12-11 14:28:27.929  WARN 24864 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] n.n.u.t.expressions.ExpressionProcessor  : Fragment expression "layout" is being wrapped as a Thymeleaf 3 fragment expression (~{...}) for backwards compatibility purposes.  This wrapping will be dropped in the next major version of the expression processor, so please rewrite as a Thymeleaf 3 fragment expression to future-proof your code.  See https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/451 for more information.
2017-12-11 14:28:31.488  WARN 24864 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 4 errors
Field error in object 'user' on field 'lastName': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.user.lastName,NotBlank.lastName,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.lastName,lastName]; arguments []; default message [lastName]]; default message [Value cannot be empty]
Field error in object 'user' on field 'password': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.user.password,NotBlank.password,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.password,password]; arguments []; default message [password]]; default message [Value cannot be empty]
Field error in object 'user' on field 'cell': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.user.cell,NotBlank.cell,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.cell,cell]; arguments []; default message [cell]]; default message [Value cannot be empty]
Field error in object 'user' on field 'firstName': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.user.firstName,NotBlank.firstName,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.firstName,firstName]; arguments []; default message [firstName]]; default message [Value cannot be empty]
2017-12-11 14:28:31.497 ERROR 24864 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-8] Exception processing template "org.springframework.validation.BeanPrope[...]e [Value cannot be empty]": Error resolving template "org.springframework.validation.BeanPrope[...]e [Value cannot be empty]", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "org.springframework.validation.BeanPrope[...]e [Value cannot be empty]", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:870) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
2017-12-11 14:28:31.499 ERROR 24864 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "org.springframework.validation.BeanPrope[...]e [Value cannot be empty]", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "org.springframework.validation.BeanPrope[...]e [Value cannot be empty]", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: The `BindingResult` **must** directly follow the argument it applies to, in your case the `@ModelAttribute` annotated argument.

Comment: Oh damn! That solve it! Would you please make the comment as answer so I accept it? Oh and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clearly stated in [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args).

> Validation results for the command/form object data binding; this argument must be declared immediately after the command/form object in the controller method signature.

So your `BindingResult` must directly follow your `@ModelAttribute` annotated method. If that isn't the case then when validation fails an exception will be thrown.